# DateTime data type, MySQL and Yii

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, yii

Let's pretend I have a table in MySQL with a field of the type `DateTime`. Let's call that field `fa`.

Now let's pretend I have the following code in Yii 1 (1.1.16):

```
$model = MyTable->createNewModel(); // <-- pseudo code
$model->fa = new DateTime("now");
$model->save();

$model = MyTable->getByPk(1); // <-- pseudo code
$model->fa; // <-- question 1
$model->fa = $model->fa->modify("+1 month"); // <-- question 2
$model->save();
```

I have the following questions:

**Question 1:**

What type is the variable `$model->fa` (at the line with the comment that says 'question 1')? Is it a string? Is it a PHP's `DateTime` type? Or is it some sort of Yii representation of `DateTime`?

**Question 2:**

If the anwers of my previous question is "PHP's `DateTime` type", then the line with the comment that says "question 2" is perfectly valid, and there shouldn't be any problems with it. But what is the type of `$model->fa` isn't PHP's `DateTime` type? How would I add 1 month to `$model->fa`?

Also please note that I know I could just hack around with `format` and make an ugly solution that involves parsing from/to my own format representation of date/time, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Have you tried using `var_dump($model)` to determine the datatypes of all the properties?

Comment: This is a PHP issue, not a yii issues, Please edit your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 : 
 Yes it must be in DateTime type.

Q2 : 
 You can use this function to add one month to your dateTime variable.

```
function addMonth($iDate,$num = 1)
{
    $date = $iDate->format('Y-n-j');
    list($y, $m, $d) = explode('-', $date);

    $m += $num;
    while ($m > 12)
    {
        $m -= 12;
        $y++;
    }

    $last_day = date('t', strtotime("$y-$m-1"));
    if ($d > $last_day)
    {
        $d = $last_day;
    }


    $fDate = new DateTime();
    return $fDate->setDate($y, $m, $d);
}
```

Comment: If `fa` is DateTime type, I can actually use the `modify` method ( http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.modify.php ).

Comment: Yes you can use it , but for me i didn't want to 2014-12-01 result for 2014-10-31 Date. And i use this function just because of it.